# ¿Oración causal o final?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Es la frase en negrita una oración causal o final?

> *Decía que los gallos estaban malditos porque se habían prestado **para que a Cristo lo negaran tres veces**.*

Comment: Es un *propósito*.

Comment: En las oraciones con sujetos con volición las subordinadas finales también pueden considerarse causales en la mayoría de los casos. Si uno se baña para estar limpio, ¿estar limpio es la finalidad o la causa? Puede ser solo finalidad, puede considerarse también causa. Sea como sea, ninguna de las dos alternativas es incorrecta. En tu caso, yo diría finalidad (o incluso a lo mejor complemento de régimen), pero considerarlo de causa también está bien.

Answer (score 5):

En

> Los gallos estaban malditos **porque se habían prestado para que negaran tres veces a Cristo.**

la oración en negrita es **causal**, pues "*haberse prestado para eso*" es la causa o razón de la maldición de los gallos.

Pero ésa no es tu pregunta.

En

> (Los gallos) se habían prestado **para que negaran tres veces a Cristo**.

la oración en negrita es **final** porque "*negar a Cristo*" es la finalidad, objetivo o meta que tuvieron los gallos al haberse prestado. La mejor palabra en realidad es *propósito*, como comentó Ustanak.

Hay tres oraciones una dentro de otra, por eso puede ser un poco confuso, pero la oración que tú marcas es en definitiva **final**.

Answer (score 3):

Como complemento de la respuesta de Rodrigo, se puede establecer el siguiente análisis:

```
Decía
|    que
|    los gallos estaban malditos
|    |    porque
|    |    se habían prestado
|    |    |    para que
|    |    |    a Cristo lo negaran tres veces.
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    (finalidad u objetivo de lo que expresa la oración anterior)
|    |    (causa de lo que expresa la oración anterior)
|    (el mensaje que es dicho por el sujeto principal)
(el verbo principal, con un sujeto tácito)
```

Es importante notar el rol que juegan las conjunciones, que en el cuadro anterior fueron dejadas en una línea propia. Cada una de las cuatro oraciones anteriores son oraciones propiamente tales, cuyo período c/r a las anteriores está marcado por las conjunciones:

> Él decía
>   Los gallos estaban malditos
>   Los gallos se habían prestado (para algo)
>   Ellos negaran tres veces a cristo